# Load more rows from MySQL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to load more than 10 rows from my table with jQuery, but it's not working.

**My php code: (...chat.php?load=archive)**

```
} else if (isset($_GET["load"]) && $_GET["load"] == "archive") {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/js/chatArchive.js'></script>";

    $limit = (int)$_POST["limit"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT ".$limit.", 2");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while($db = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "..."; // My datas...
        }
        echo "<div style='text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 10px 0;'>\n";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Load more rows' class='loadMore'>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

**My JS file: (chatArchive.js)**

```
var limit = 50;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loadMore").click(function() {
        limit += 10;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../../system/functions/chat.php?load=archive",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "limit" : limit },
            success: function() {
                alert("Success...");
                console.log(limit); // This displayed my console!!!
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: `success` function has an argument. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Function which is defined as a callback for `success` property has an argument, usually called `data`, which is the returned value from your script. So, you should change your success function as follows:

```
success: function(data) {    // see data here
    alert("Success...");
    console.log(limit); // This displayed my console!!!

    console.log( data );    // check what data contains
}
```

Also it's a good practice to add `error` callback, which will indicate that something bad happens:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../../system/functions/chat.php?load=archive",
        ....
        error: function() {
            alert("Bad thing happenned!");
        }
)};
```

Answer (score -1):

your ajax method is POST but in your php script you check GET request

```
 if (isset($_GET["load"]) && $_GET["load"] == "archive")
```

Change Your ajax method to GET